# Export dicky-fuller test to latex table

Tags: r, time-series

I'm running augmented Dicky-Fuller tests with [`URCA`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/urca/index.html) package. I've been searching a way to export the output showed by applying summary to the object created with `ur.df()`, however I haven't found anything so far.

The output from summary shows me all what I need to export to a LaTeX table.

I thought in creating a table taking the elements of the object but it is a S4 class which doesn't allow me to take elements of it.

```
## Dicky-Fuller test for Real Output 

Y.df <- ur.df(Y, type = "trend", selectlags = c("AIC"))

summary(Y.df)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It helps others help you when you provide a [mcve]. Specifically, no one can re-create `Y.df` without access to your data, `Y`. You can read some R-specific information about making minimal reproducible examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). One thing you may want to look into is the [`xtable`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/index.html) package.